# I want to use withPivot with morphMany in Laravel 5.2 and that gives me an error, what can I use instead for polymorphic relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a table votes that looks like this:

```
id
user_id
votable_id
votable_type
status
```

I need to be able to set the status so I thought this would work:

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    public function votes(){
        return $this->morphMany(Vote::class, 'votable')->withPivot('status');
    }
}
```

However that gives this error:

```
BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::withPivot()'
```

Comment: There is no need to use `->withPivot('status')` since there is no pivot-table, right? The status is already inside the votes table so it should show op in the result of the query. Try `dd()` the result and update your question with the output.

Comment: As far as I know, `->withPivot()` only works on `belongsToMany()`

Comment: thanks guys I figured it out.